# Removing printer marks from a PDF file

Tags: pdf, editing

I need to remove the printer marks from a PDF file. I am using Acrobat 9 Professional to open the PDF, but there is no option for removing the printer marks although there is option to add new printer marks.

I googled and found that there is a third-party plugin "Enfocus PitStop" which when installed is added to Adobe Acrobat and provides an option to remove the print marks, but that software is quite costly.

Is there any way I can remove the printer marks programmatically or through the Adobe Acrobat 9.0 interface?

Comment: You mean registration marks, crop marks etc?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 7):

Using the View > Navigation Panels > Content box worked well for me. I was able to delete the cut lines without an issue.

Answer (score 3):

In Acrobat Professional, go to Document > Crop Pages and select "Trim Box" from the dropdown menu. If the document doesn't have this dimension built in, you can also manually enter it.

You can also edit PDFs in Adobe Illustrator, if available.

Answer (score 2):

How to Manually Remove Printers Marks in Adobe Acrobat

Open File 
Save File As (rename to preserve original)

Go to: Document > Crop Pages
    In the first drop down box, select trim box (or other as necessary)
    Adjust the margin numbers as needed to save required bleeds
    Note the margin numbers.

Close the window

Go to: View > Navigation Panels > Content
    Move window out of your way so you can see your .pdf and this box
    Zoom in on .pdf so you can see detail
    Go back to Content window
    Click the + next to .pdf name
    Click the + next to the page number
        *This will now show the various parts of the .pdf.
    Select any component and right click
    Select highlight content.
        *Your page will now jump to that item and put a small box around it.

Scroll through content to find all printer marks to be removed. (I suggest starting at the bottom and viewing each item to identify a group.  (the bottom 5 “paths) for example.  Select them all and delete them)

All Printer Marks should now be removed. Close the Content window

Go to: Document > Crop Pages
    Type in the top crop dimension you obtained earlier and hit ENTER.
    Continue for the Bottom, Left and Right Sides.

*Note – I was not able to enter all dimensions at once and have the crop actually executed.

Save File

Answer (score 2):

I had red registration lines that were NOT crop lines and finally found out how to remove then as follows (I'm using Acrobat Professional 7):

View >> Navigation Tabs >> Content

A window opens with 4 tabs (Fields/Tags/Content/Order)
Stay on Content Tab
Click on File Name (Pages Open)
Click on Page in Question (Details open)

Click on items called "Path" and delete one at time
 - If the wrong line dissappears press Ctrl-Z to get it back

Through trial and error I was able to eliminate the lines.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just had to remove the registration/bleed marks on a 155 page PDF file, and figured I'd share my solution.  This is in Acrobat Pro 10.1

Since the document was meant for 8.5 x 11 paper, I went

1. File > Print
2. Printer: Adobe PDF
3. Pages: All
4. Size Options: Actual size

As long as the registration marks are accurate for the size of the paper you're "printing" to, the result should be a new PDF with pages that fall within the registration marks, effectively cropping them all off.

Answer (score 1):

I Just automated this process for a 40 page PDF in Acrobat Pro without plug-ins.

Open your Tools pane click Pages > Crop > Draw a box around your content, double click and apply to all pages. Quick and easy!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone also has the issue, that they need to have the contents outside of the dropbox **really** removed, I came across this [post](http://www.proficiografik.com/2009/11/17/acrobat-9-when-the-crop-tool-is-not-cropping-and-how-to-fix-it.html): http://www.proficiografik.com/2009/11/17/acrobat-9-when-the-crop-tool-is-not-cropping-and-how-to-fix-it.html

It includes a [preflight setting](http://www.proficiografik.com/sharing/CropBoxFix.kfp.zip) which completely removes ANY objects outside of the crop / trim / media box and sets the boundary to the trim box.
Any other solution just **HIDES** the contents, but does not remove them, which cause them to re-appear in e.g. Ipad applications.

I prefer to do the cropping in Acrobat, because Ghostscript sometimes has problems in processing certain PDFs.

Comment: The site does not work anymore, but the archived version is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190124162549/www.proficiografik.com/2009/11/17/acrobat-9-when-the-crop-tool-is-not-cropping-and-how-to-fix-it.html) and the preflight setting is archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408145318/www.proficiografik.com/sharing/CropBoxFix.kfp.zip) – it still works even in the latest version of Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove them by directly editing the pdf file in Textpad (Notepad might work also) and changing the values for the /cropbox setting.
It has 4 values after it for left, top, right and bottom crop positions and mine were set the same as the preceeding /mediabox values.
I was able to add 120 to the first two values and take 120 off the second two and that cropped the page when it was next opened in Acrobat Reader.
It might need a bit of trial and error to get the correct values but it did the trick for me.  Just change the first one and once it's correct you can do a scan/replace to change the value for the other pages.
Could be an option for people if you have no way of editing it via Acrobat, either because the file is protected or because you don't have access to the pro version.

Answer (score -3):

If you mean registration watermarks, either you have to crack the software (which I am not telling you to do) or you have to buy it. Usually, free pdf writers/editors include a watermark unless you buy the product. If however you wanted a free pdf printer, try CutePDF. I at least think this is what you are asking about.