# Perl code to find crop marks in PDFs

Tags: perl, pdf

Is it possible to find the crop marks in PDF files using Perl code? 
Is it possible to find whether the PDF file has been optimized or not?

Please suggest the solutions if the above cases are possible using perl scripting...

Comment: Do you know how the PDF's were created?  If the crop marks are in an embedded image it's a different problem than if they were inserted as a vector e.g. with Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape.

Comment: The PDFs are created from adobe indesign files. Is it possible in perl that to communicate with acrobat professional?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/module/Wx::ActiveX::Acrobat will give you access to the scripting interface, another option would be to use the JavaScript interface.

Comment: What are you trying to do once you find the crop marks?

Comment: I need to remove the crop marks, if its found in PDF. There is fixed width and height in crop-marks. I am doing perl programming in Windows XP. Batch processing is possible in acrobat professional. But is any other options is there to import those functionality in perl?

Comment: Is it necessary to do this programmatically (for example, to you need to do this to a large amount of files)?  If not you may find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212256/removing-printer-marks-from-a-pdf-file.  If so I'll supply a suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into [PDF::API2](https://metacpan.org/module/PDF%3a%3aAPI2), check out the page methods https://metacpan.org/module/PDF::API2#PAGE-METHODS, checkout the `cropbox` method.  There may be a solution there.